# How can I split a beamer bibliography across two slides?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, page-breaking

I have several citations in a `beamer`-based presentation.  Is it possible to split the bibliography across two slides?  I'm using `natbib` / `bibtex`.  And I currently just have:

```
\begin{frame}

\tiny

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Biblio-Database}

\end{frame}
```

But we're to the point where even *tiny* won't cut it.  Is there anyway to do this?  I'd really prefer to *not* create the bibliography by hand because I once had it 'stuck to me' that I omitted an entry in the bibliography (which I'd created by hand)... nothing quite like ending on a clerical omission...

Answer (score 211, accepted):

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Biblio-Database}

\end{frame}
```

**done.** [I found this here :O)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913966/how-to-split-table-of-contents-across-multiple-slides-with-latex-beamer)

Answer (score 25):

For people working with:

```
\frame{  
bla bla   
Content on the slide  
bla bla  
}
```

the `[allowframebreaks]` has to be places like this:

```
\frame[allowframebreaks]{  
\tiny\bibliography{Name of your Bibliographie}  
\bibliographystyle{Your bibliographystyle}  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those working with biblatex on Overleaf this works fine :

```latex
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Literature References}
    \tiny
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0):

For people working with pandoc markdown, you do it like this:

```markdown
## References {.allowframebreaks}
```