# Long bibliography in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am a new user of the Beamer presentation template and would like to display an extensive reference list with numbers to the left of the entries just as the standard bibliography in LaTeX. How can I do so? My bibliography does not fit into a single slide and I think there should be a neat solution for it. Could you provide some suggestions?

EDIT: I have managed to split my bibliography across many slides now I would like to enumerate them just like in LaTeX document class. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20660/18228

Comment: @KevinC Well probably thanks for pointing that out I will inspect it more closely.

Comment: If that question does help, we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @KevinC I managed to split my bibliography across many slides now I would like to enumerate the entries just like in LaTeX. How can I do so?

Comment: Try `\bibliographystyle{plain}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

Comment: @KevinC Actually I noticed no difference in between these two. By the way I write the bibliography inside the document instead of calling it from an external file if that makes a difference.

Comment: How about `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]`?