# adjust text's size in beamer when bibliography is too long

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, fontsize

Im a using `beamer` and my bibliogrpahy is too long to fit on one single frame.

My code is very simple :

```
\begin{frame}%[allowframebreaks=0.9]
\section*{Bibliographie}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

I could use `[allowframebreak=0.9]` option, for example, to divide it in three frames, but that is not what I want : I would like the text to **get smaller** so that it fits on one frame. So my case is not [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides) nor [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155648/long-bibliography-in-beamer-presentation).

Beamer's manual (speaks about `bibtex`, and not `biblatex`) gives me this great answer :

> The environment must be placed inside a frame. If the bibliography does not fit on one frame, you should split it (create a new frame and a second  `thebibliography` environment) or use the `allowframebreaks` option. Even better, you should reconsider whether it is a good idea to present so many references. (p.101)

Thank you, but I've reconsidered it, and I think it's a good idea. At least, I want to see if it's still readable when reduced before my decision to split it or reduce it.

I've tried something like `{\tiny \printbibliography}` but it doesn't work.

Can someone help ? Thank you.

Comment: Is this for presentation or to distribute to readers? If presentation, then nobody will read it. If distribution, it doesn't matter how many pages it takes.

Comment: This is for presentation. But the only thing is I would like to see how it looks before deciding what to do whith it : if I see that it's too small, well, I will have seen it by my own eyesand decide to split it.

I also hope that such a command would allow me to adjust the text's size to the frame's size, in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fit an arbitrary amount of text on a frame, you can use the `shrink` option.  Without any value it will not change the linewidth before shrinking, with a value such as `shrink=10` it will increase line widths corresponding to that of a `10%` reduction before doing the shrinking.

Here is an example with one slide with text generated by the `lipsum` package, the other from a bibliography.  Note `\section` does not work in a `frame`, use `\frametitle` instead.

All this is "evil" in the terminology of the `beamer` manual.

[image: First sample]

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]
  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=90]
  \frametitle{Bibliography}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks in the world i wouldn't dare doing, but still think *Cooool*.

Comment: Thank you !

At least I can decide if I want to : reduce my bibliography, shrink the size, or split it in different frames.

I've also moved the `\section` outside from the frame.