# Does justifying and `frame breaks' conflict in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, bibliographies

I tried the justifying techniques proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55589/text-justify-in-beamer): My presentation in Beamer document class also have long bibliography. I have used **allow frame breaks** in a new frame which recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides). Surprisingly, frame breaks stopped working! If I comment out **\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}** as suggested for justifying then frame breaks work again. I am new in LaTex. Please help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}    

\mode<presentation> {
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{} %comment out this line will not let me justified but frame break for bibliography works then!
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. I am confused. Please help. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Reference}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Thesis_presentation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you put `\justifying` just after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: @Harish I do not see any change by doing that! Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CBT.png

Comment: @Harish Thank you. It works for me too. Sorry for the earlier comment, i misunderstood that. Now the frame breaks works as it should be.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments