# Split biblio over multiple slides (beamer) with allowframebreaks

Tags: beamer, bibtex, bibliographies

I have too many references for a single slide (I am using beamer on Sharelatex) and while looking for a solution I bumped into this:

[How can I split a beamer bibliography across two slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides)

I tried and follow the suggestions given in the post but allowframebreaks does not work properly. In particular, I can compile and produce a pdf without getting errors, but what I see is a first empty slide (References), and a second (References II) slide overstuffed with my citations.

Can anyone give some help? 
I am not that expert in using beamer and I need to sort this out asap.
Many thanks in advance.

Here is my code and the corresponding output:

```
 \documentclass[xcolor=svgnames,handout]{beamer}
 \usepackage[utf8] {inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]  {fontenc}
 \usepackage[english] {babel}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
 \usepackage{FabioSimpleStyle}
 \usepackage{verbatim}%comment environment
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{DoWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}

   \title[Computational intelligence optimisation\hspace{2em}]{An introduction to real world optimisation}
   \author[name]{Fabio}
   \date{Academic year 2015-2016}
  \institute{university}

  \begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \begin{frame}{NFLT}{bla bla bla?}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \cite{bib:freelunches}.
      \item hyper-heuristics\footnote{for... \cite       {bib:Burke2010,bib:Ozcan2008}} \cite{polilunches}.
    \end{itemize},\cite{bib:Hooke-Jeeves1961}, \cite{bib:Caraffini2012PMS}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
      \frametitle{References}
      \bibliographystyle{apalike}
     \bibliography{demo}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Then send a MWE (minimal working example, a short, self containing document) which exhibits your problem ASAP  ... In usual circumstances this, what you describe in question, shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks Zarko, I have added code and output.. is that what you need?

Comment: What is in package `FabioSimpleStyle`. Seems to be private package ... Without it all seems o.k. Unfortunately `\bibliography{demo}` not work in my LaTeX installation (MikTeX) ...

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. With one of mine .bib file and without your private `FabioSimpleStyle` work as expected. From picture of your slides I conclude, that you actually import your `bibliography` as picture, which can't be fir in one frame. Is this a case?

Comment: Thanks a lot Zarko it is working now... I just slightly modified a .sty file that I found on the web and it contained a strange definition for the biblio using pictures. I just commented that bit and it seems OK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a) can not be reproduced without unavailable custom style files and b) solved according to comments