# Split references in beamer with allowframebreaks results in phantom pages

Tags: beamer, apacite

Using the `beamer` document class, I would like to split a long list of references over multiple slides.  As recommended by [M. Tibbits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1393/m-tibbits) in [another stack exchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides), one should use `allowframebreaks`.  This, however, resulted in two unnecessary page breaks after the final slide before the appendix.  See the working example below.  Note that if `[allowframebreaks]` is removed, then the two phantom pages disappear.

Question: Why do the phantom pages appear, and how do I get rid of them?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[unnumberedbib,bibnewpage]{apacite}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a citation \citeA{citation1}
\item This is another citation \citeA{citation2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{flushleft}
\bibliography{stack_exchange_library}
\end{flushleft}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My library, `stack_exchange_library.bib`, is:

```
 @article{citation1,
  title={Title of citation 1},
  author={Smith, John},
  journal={Blacksmithing},
  year={2010},
}

@article{citation2,
  title={Title of citation 1},
  author={Farmer, Joe},
  journal={Farming},
  year={2011},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `bibnewpage` from the `apacite` options. In normal text documents this triggers the bibliography to be on a new page, but this does not make sense in beamer as you are already in a new frame.