# How to shrink the font size of references in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm preparing slides for my dissertation proposal. I want to include my bibliography on the last slide, but the references don't quite fit on one slide. Here's a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{apacite}

\title[A BNP Beta-Mixture IRT Model]
{A Bayesian Nonparametric Beta-Mixture\\Item Response Model}
\author[E. A. Arenson]
{Ethan A. Arenson}
\date{August 30, 2017}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample Slide}
Random text \cite{Random Author}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Dissertation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The \footnotesize command in the "References" frame does not reduce the font size of the references. How can I either reduce the font size or split the reference list across two slides?

Comment: [Split the reference with](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides) with `\frame[allowframebreaks]{`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although I had to use the command `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]`.

Comment: You are absolutly right, sorry for missspelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the manual of `apacite`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{apacite}
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\footnotesize}
\begin{document}

\nocite{knuth:ct:c}

\begin{frame}{References}
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
  \bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I put the `\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\small}` command before the `\begin{document}` command. I get this error message in the log:
`! Undefined control sequence.
l.43 \renewcomammand
                    \bibliographytypesize{\small}
`
with a split between the `\renewcommand` and `bibliographytypesize` commands.

Comment: @EthanArenson It's `\renewcommand` not `\renewcomammand`.  Also this has to come after `\usepackage{apacite}`.