# How to solve these two problems with Beamer?

Tags: beamer, apacite

This is the two problems I'm trying to solve: 1. A title, which I don't want here, appears in my TOC. How to remove it? 2. The command \cite{} does not work: any of my references appear in the dedicated section. I request your help. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{default}
    \usepackage{soul}
    \usepackage{framed,color}
    %\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1.0, 0.8, 0.3}
    \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.74, 0.83, 0.9}
    %\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.95, 0.83, 0.86}
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
    \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{helvet}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%paragraphes justifiés%%%%%
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} % Allow optional arguments after frame.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%footline%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \addtobeamertemplate{footnote}{}{\vspace{2ex}}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
      \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}Title\hfill\insertshortsubtitle\hfill\strut\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%NUMÉROTATION TOC%%%%%%%%
    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection\par}
    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsectionnumber.\inserttocsubsectionnumber.~\inserttocsubsection\par}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %\useinnertheme{circles}
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
    \makeatother
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    %\usepackage{apacite}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PLAN%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \AtBeginSubsection[]
    {
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Plan}
    \tableofcontents[
      currentsection,
      sectionstyle=show/show,
      subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
    ]
    \end{frame}
    }
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \title{\textbf{Title}}
    \subtitle[]{Colloque}
    \author{My name}
    
    \date{}
    
    
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
        @Book{Anzieu1993,
    author = {Anzieu, Didier and Haag, Geneviève and Tisseron, Serge and Lavallée, Guy and Boubli, Myriam and Lassègue, Jean}, 
    title = {Les contenants de pensée}, 
    volume = {}, 
    pages = {}, 
    editor = {}, 
    publisher = {Dunod}, 
    address = {Paris}, 
    year = {1993}, 
    abstract = {}, 
    keywords = {contenance; pensée; penser},
    }
    
    @Book{Anzieu1994,
    author = {Anzieu, Didier}, 
    title = {Le Penser. Du Moi-peau au Moi-pensant}, 
    volume = {}, 
    pages = {}, 
    editor = {}, 
    publisher = {Dunod}, 
    address = {Paris}, 
    year = {1994}, 
    abstract = {}, 
    keywords = {},
    }
    
    \end{filecontents}
    \usepackage[]{apacite}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{frame}{\normalsize{Déroulement}}
    \tableofcontents    
    \end{frame}
    
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}
        \cite{Anzieu1993}
        
            \cite{Anzieu1994}
    \end{frame}
    
    
    \section{Développement}
    \begin{frame}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    
    
    \section{Conclusion}
    \begin{frame}
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    %\renewcommand{\bibliographytypesize}{\tiny}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: For the second problem I'm not sure what you mean, in your MWE the citations show on the Introduction slide (as (Anzieu et al., 1993) and (Anzieu, 1994)), and the bibliography shows on the final slide. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @Marijn's comment solves your `toc` problem. For the second problem, are you compiling with `pdflatex`,  `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`? If that's not the problem, then you need to make the second problem clearer. You may want to load `apacite` with the `[natbibapa]` option unless you are used to using the classic `apacite` citation commands.

Comment: First problem solved. But my references does not appear nor in the frames nor in the references section. "LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references"

Comment: That probably means that you didn't run `bibtex`, as @AlanMunn has mentioned. Another option is that you misspelled the cite keys so they are not the same in the document and in the `.bib` file.

Comment: It finally works! But now, my references exceed the limits of the bibliography section... Any idea?

Comment: @domi see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20660/how-can-i-split-a-beamer-bibliography-across-two-slides